# Is that possible to set jvm parameters of jolokia agent for war with gradle？

Tags: tomcat, gradle, war, jvm-arguments

I want to add some configurations for my tomcat application. It builds as a war with gradle war plugin. Currently I use env to set the jvm parameters , which is not convenient at all, so that I can use jolokia agent. Is that possible to set jvm parameters for war file with gradle? And how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jolokia **[JEE Agent(WAR)](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html#agents-war)** can solve this.

- 1. Add servlet of tomcat

  `web.xml
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jolokia-agent</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jolokia-agent</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/jolokia/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`
- 2. Add dependency of jolokia with gradle

`compile group: 'org.jolokia', name: 'jolokia-core', version: '1.3.5'`

After these, MBeans of jvm and application is available now.

More details blow:
https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html